# Proxy Server functionalities in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, proxy, flex3

Please explain me briefly what is proxy server and what does it do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it have to do with ActionScript 3 and Flex3? :S

Comment: @Ranhiru Cooray - Thanks for responding. I do not have much knowledge on Proxy. That's why asked about it. If possible explain it in your way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good [explanation and tutorial.](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Creating+a+BlazeDS+web+service+application+in+Flex+Builder)

Comment: Thank you @jcsf. It helped me to get knowledge on it :)